# SSAS browser class not registered error

Tags: sql-server, browser, ssas

Hi I'm getting the following error when I try to use the cube browser in Business Intelligence Studio. The standard solution of reinstalling OWC 2003 does not work. I do have several versions of SQL installed on the dev machine and was wondering if that could be the problem as some posts mention it but don't go into detail. Cheers, Chris.

SSAS Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Answer (score 0):

I avoid using the cube browser - it is unreliable, doesnt scale and doesnt accurately reflect the user experience or the MDX generated by your client tools.  Your clients/users are not using OWC 2003 - right?

IMO you should use the client tool your users are using, so that you see the structure as they will see it, and generate the MDX and results that they will get.

I prefer Excel for browsing the cube.  It has many advantages e.g. saved "queries" and results, easily compare results from multiple queries / sources, quite scalable.

Comment: I'd still like to get the brower working. It's what I'm familiar with. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled SQL 2008 R2 which I had as well as 2008 and reinstalled OWA and it started working.